# Setting up OIDC via Auth0 for a web site that is hosted on customer networks

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, openid-connect

As part of a process to update/secure/centralize our auth and licensing process, we are looking at using OIDC via Auth0. Part of our package is a web site that is typically hosted on customer networks. We are trying to figure out the appropriate flow to use in this situation. It seems like we would need to set up an appropriate Callback URL for the applications which would need to point at the customer hosted instances.

Is there more appropriate flow that doesn't require that callback? What is the appropriate way to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you will always need a Callback URL when it comes to the authentication workflow that way you know where to redirect users after login. I have attached documentation supporting this process. I hope this helps you in your adventure!

https://auth0.com/docs/users/guides/redirect-users-after-login